# How to deploy a user based CA certificates to the domain joined Ubuntu Clients through landscape?

Tags: 22.04, landscape

User-based certificates help the user to connect to the enterprise wireless connectivity!

We have a set of Ubuntu Clients managed through landscape. Now the clients require a CA certificate to connect to the enterprise wireless network, I would like to know how the certificates can be delivered to the clients via landscape. For Windows, the same certificates are delivered through GPO. Certificates are use-based and will be provided by the security team.

Comment: We have set of Ubuntu Clients managed through _landscape_. Now the clients requires a CA certificate to connect to the enterprise wireless network, I would like to know how the certificates can be delivered to the clients via landscape. For Windows the same certificates are delivered through GPO. Certificates are use based which will be provided by the security team.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu.  It's better if you edit the question and add additional information to it instead of replying in a comment.  I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Thank You Rohit.